# C - Weird issue with printed text splitting itself into multiple lines?

Tags: c

Sorry if this is an obvious question but I've searched around quite a bit and I can't see any answers. I'm having a weird issue where my printed statements are being broken without specifying a line break. My code is:

```
int main(){
    int arrSize;
    printf("How many elements is the array:");
    scanf("%d", &arrSize);

    int array[arrSize];
    for (int i = 0; i < arrSize; i++){
        printf("Enter element %d:", i);
        scanf("%d", &array[i]);
    }
    char decision;
    printf("Would you like to convert your array to a linked list? ");
    scanf(" %c", &decision);

    if (decision == 'Y'){
        node_n *head = ArrayToLL(array, arrSize);
        print_list(head);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

If I specify and enter 3 elements, the print statement appears like:

```
How many elements is the array:3
Enter element 0:1
Enter element 1:2
Enter element 2:3
Would you like to convert your array to a
 linked list?Y
 1 2 3
```

You can see there is a weird line break for some reason?
Any help much appreciated!

```
void print_list(node_n *head) {
    node_n *current = head;
    while (current != NULL){
        printf("%d ", current->data);
        current = current->next;
    }
};
```

Comment: Are you sure that output was generated by the posted code? The code outputs a space after `'?'` which is absent at the output.

Comment: You might be having some invisible characters where you think the spaces are. But yeah, looks like the code does not correspond to the output shown

Comment: Also show us the function `print_list()`

Comment: Hi Guys, yes I am sure the window is wide enough and to answer Weather Vane - This output was definitely generated by the code I showed. The print_list() function takes place after the break so I don't see how it can be involved in the issue. Nonetheless the code is now in the original post ^

Comment: Are you perhaps running this inside an IDE, with output connected to a panel or window managed by that IDE?  Because I see no way to accept the assertion that the code presented is responsible for the output presented unless there is some other layer between.

Comment: John you are right! I just tried running this code in CodeBlocks and the issue disappears. I was previously running it in CLion, which was the IDE creating the issue for some reason. Thanks!